# UISearchController not updating with PFQueryTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

Attempting to implement a UISearchController on my app using Parse.com to query. There are some examples online but for the older 'UISearchDisplayController' which is now deprecated.

Anyways I seem to got everything working correctly as far as searching and querying (according to my NSLog) but the tableview isn't getting updated at all, and I'm not sure why.

Here is what I've done:

```
@interface LocalSalesViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults; // Filtered search results

@end

@implementation LocalSalesViewController
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Sales";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    LocalSalesTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[LocalSalesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

        object = (tableView == self.tableView) ? self.objects[indexPath.row] : self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

        cell.saleTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;


}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {


        return self.objects.count;

    } else {

        return self.searchResults.count;

    }
}


#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString = [self.searchController.searchBar text];
    [self updateFilteredContentForSaleName:searchString];
     [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
}
#pragma mark - Content Filtering
- (void)updateFilteredContentForSaleName:(NSString *)saleName {
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    for (PFObject *sale in self.objects)
    {
        NSString *saleTitle = [sale objectForKey:@"name"];
        if ([[saleTitle lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[saleName lowercaseString]])
        {
            [self.searchResults addObject:sale];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.searchResults);

}
```

It appears the self.searchResults log is doing everything its supposed to by filtering the ones out and adding to the array, but no cells are being updated at all what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, calling `initWithSearchResultsController:nil` means self will be the view controller used to display the results.

So `((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView` is self.tableView

So `if (tableView == self.tableView)` will always be `true`.